# Explode Data from MySQL and pass the value with json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, explode

i am really new in explode and implode. I want to explode data from my database and enter the value to array so i can pass it to my HTML page with json_encode

This is my PHP file

```
<?php
session_start();
include "config.php";
$zzz = array();
$pass = array();
$idacara=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
$mysql = ("select kategori from acara where id_acara='$idacara'");
$result=mysql_query($mysql);
if (!empty($result))
{
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $temp = explode(",",$row['kategori']);
        $count = count($temp);
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
        {
            $zzz=$pass[$i];
        }
        $fetchkategori[] = array
        (
            'kategori' => $zzz
        );

    }
}

mysql_close($con);

header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode($fetchkategori);
?>
```

This is my Ajax in HTML File

```
var arrKategori=new Array();
        $.ajax({
            url: host+'/skripsi3/phpmobile/kategori.php',
            data: { "id": getacara},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, status){
                $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                    if (arrKategori.indexOf(item.idkat)<0)
                    {   
                        $("fieldset").append('<input type="radio" name="radiokategori" class="required" id="'+item.idkat+'" value="'+item.idkat+'" required><label for="'+item.idkat+'">'+item.kategori+'</label>').trigger("create");  
                        arrKategori.push(item.idkat);

                    }       
                });
            },
            error: function(){
                //output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
            }
        });
```

Thank You Before and Have a nice day :D

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Hey @aldrin27 Thank you for your fast response, my question is how to enter exploded data to array so it can be passed to my HTML with json encode. In my HTML the value will show as radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, do not use `mysql_*` functions. Instead use use `mysqli_*` or **PDO** functions.

You have to declare `$fetchkategori[]` outside the first `if` block in following way

```
$fetchkategori = array();
```

After that inside `while` loop, store the array in the following way.

```
$fetchkategori[] = array
    (
        'kategori' => $zzz
    );
```

Your code will work.

**Here is a complete solution using `mysqli`**

**config.php**

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli('mysql_hostname', 'mysql_username', 'mysql_password', 'mysql_database');
```

**PHP file**

```
        <?php
    session_start();
    include "config.php";
    $zzz = array();
    $pass = array();
    $fetchkategori = array();
    $idacara=$_GET["id"];
    //preparing query
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select kategori from acara where id_acara=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $idacara);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();//add this line
    $stmt->bind_result($kategori);
    if ($stmt->num_rows>0)
    {
        while ($stmt->fetch())
        {
            $temp = $kategori;
            $count = count($temp);
            for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
            {
                $zzz=$pass[$i];
            }
            $fetchkategori[] = array
            (
                'kategori' => $zzz
            );

        }
    }

    mysqli_close($mysqli);

    header('Content-Type:application/json');
    echo json_encode($fetchkategori);
    ?>
```

Comment: it not working, There is an error message 
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsi3\phpmobile\kategori.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
[]

Comment: and if i use mysql, an error message
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 0 in 
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 1 in 
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 2 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsi3\phpmobile\kategori.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 3 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsi3\phpmobile\kategori.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 4 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsi3\phpmobile\kategori.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />
{"kategori":null}

Comment: hey, thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it not work there is an error <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsi3\phpmobile\kategori.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
[]